# Use multiple components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I'm creating a project using it. I have a problem while using multiple components. Here is the scenario

when the page is loaded both component is loaded  values of type,getcpeyearlysval and getvnfyearlysval are set

```
  setDataMeter1(){
     //here i want only type cpe componnet will load
     }

 <Speedometer type = "cpe" getcpeyearlysval={this.objSpeedometer.getcpeyearlys}/>
  <Speedometer type = "vnf" getvnfyearlysval={this.objSpeedometer.getvnfyearlys}/>
```

Now I want when I to call this.setDataMeter1 function only type cpe component should work, but the problem is both calls.

```
<select value={this.state.selectValue}  onChange={this.setDataMeter1}>

In Speedometer component:
   renderIcon(key, val) {
      if(key == 'vnf') {
        console.log("vnf")
      }
      if(key == 'cpe'){
        console.log("cpe")// this condition should met
      }
   }
    render() {
        return (
            this.renderIcon(this.props.type, this.props)
        );
    }
}
```

But my problem is both conditions mets in speedometer components.

Comment: You need to `return null` out of your `renderIcon` function after the `vnf` condition has been met in order to stop the rendering.

Comment: this is not clear... you need to show more code

Answer (score 0):

```
   renderIcon(props) {
      if(props.type == 'vnf') {
        return <Text>hey this is vnf </Text>
      }
      if(props.type == 'cpe'){
        return <Text>hey this is cpe </Text>
      }
   }
    render() {
        return (
            this.renderIcon(this.props)
        );
    }
```